# Question marks in pdf file when referring to table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

Have a look at the MWE below. In the pdf file I get questionmarks when reffering to the table, rather than a numeric reference. Even if I run LaTeX twice. Any ideas how this can be solved?

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

we refer to table \ref{tab:ex}

\begin{table}[h]\label{tab:ex}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
9  & 12 & 8 & 10 & 9           \\ \hline
10 & 7  & 8 & 13 & \textbf{50} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need a caption, so the table gets a number and compile more than once.

Comment: After the first compilation you get question marks with an undefined reference warning because of the undefined reference. But after the second compilation you get an empty reference without any question marks. The reference is empty, because there is nothing that can be referenced. Reference the table by page number rather than a non existent page number, e.g. `see the table on page~\pageref{tab:ex}`.

Comment: I had the exact issue with figures while using the class acmart. The usual solution of running pdflatex didn't work. Also, there was no issue while using the default article class. At last, I found out that I had to put `\label` at the ending of the figure environment, not at its beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a `\caption` in your `table`. LaTeX uses the `\caption` macro to number your tables thus without a caption you won't get a number and thus cannot reference the table.

Try this:

```
\documentclass{report} 
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

we refer to table \ref{tab:ex}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Example of a simple table.}
\label{tab:ex}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
9  & 12 & 8 & 10 & 9           \\ \hline
10 & 7  & 8 & 13 & \textbf{50} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

A few things to remember:

- Typically table-captions go above the table, figure captions go below the figure (at least in european typography)
- The `\label` has to appear *after* the `\caption`, because `\caption` creates the number the `\label` can then refer to.
- If you do not want a caption you won't get a number. But it's wise to always provide a short caption at least.
- There are means to get Captions outside of `table` or `figure` environments with KOMA-Script or the `caption` package